# XShm completion event not setting Display file descriptor

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, x11

I have an event loop which is regularly calling `poll()` on a set of read file descriptors and dispatching events when they are ready to be read from. One of these file descriptors is the X connection file descriptor returned from `XConnectionNumber()` and will call the following when the file descriptor is ready:

```
XEvent evt;

if (! XPending (display))
    return false;

XNextEvent (display, &evt);

// do something with evt
```

This all works fine for receiving display events.

The repainting in my application relies on XShm extensions, it essentially calls `XShmPutImage()` to draw some pixels and then waits for a completion event until drawing again, the completion event is found by checking `evt.any.type == XShmGetEventBase (display)` in the above code.

The problem is that the XShm completion event doesn't seem to set the file descriptor of the display as being ready for I/O so I am only getting repaint events when other events are being sent to the display and setting the fd e.g. mouse moves, key events etc. This results in the app only being responsive when other events are happening.

Am I misunderstanding how the XShm completion event is sent? Shouldn't it set the Display fd?

Answer (score 1):

OK I've answered my own question. It seems that I need to set the `POLLOUT` flag on the `pollfd` struct for the display file descriptor. Previously I was only setting `POLLIN` as I was waiting for input events but XShm completion events are setting the fd as ready to write to.